# Is it ok to use a rotary hammer to make a hole in the sub dirt wall of my basement?

Tags: plumbing, outdoor

I am considering using a rotary hammer to make a 1" hole in my basement wall. I want the hole to route a pex line entirely underground out to a remote garden hose spigot on the far side of my lawn. I see a full size sewer line going out that way, so why not a small hole for pex?

Comment: Assuming you're below the frost line (or drain this connection for winter), and that you seal the opening around the hose reasonably well so it doesn't become a water infiltration point... What kind of wall is it,  how thick, and do you really want to both fight your way through that and trench down deeply enough to connect to it and run the line?

Comment: I know it will be a lot of work. It is probably 300' to where I would like to put the spigot. I would probably rent a trencher. I'm not really sure of the width of the  wall but it looks substantially wider than the 2x4 framed wall above it. But I can only see what's on the inside. I'd have a valve and blowout for winterization.

Comment: Poured concrete?

Comment: Yes. It is poured concrete.

Comment: Go for it.  Use hydraulic cement around the pipe to seal it back up.